# Faces selection wrong under linux

Tags: faces, selection-tools, linux

The problem is caused by out of curiosity rather than practicality, as relate the previous file versions (2.69-2.77).
Create cube, turn the edit mode, subdivide it several times. I click on the face to select it. But it often does not select this face (But any other). When I click again, selected can stay the same face, or select another.
OS. Fedora Linux. Under Windows no such problem

Comment: Are you in wireframe mode? If you are in face selection, it will select the face with the center point closest to the mouse.

Comment: Are you in wireframe mode? Not, I in solid mode. I have not this prolem in 2.78, But I have in 2.69-2.77.

Comment: ? I have 2.76 on linux (miint) but I can select faces as expected, even after subdividing (x10)...

Comment: In the preferences, [under opengl](https://www.blender.org/manual/preferences/system.html#opengl) there is a selection option, try a different option.

Comment: what kind of graphics card are you using?

Comment: sambler, I try it, did't help.
Videocard Nvidia GTX9600 by open driver (Not official)